# Using Kafka-Go, why am I seeing what appears to be batching reads/writes? Is there a config I am missing?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm going to be switching from RabbitMQ to Kafka. This is just a simple spike to see how Kafka operates. I'm not sure if there are settings that I am missing, if it is my code, if it is Kafka-Go, or if this is expected Kafka behavior.

I've tried adjusting the `BatchSize` as well as the `BatchTimeout` but neither have had an impact.

The code below creates a topic with 6 partitions and a replication factor of 3. It then produces an incrementing message every `100ms`. It launches 6 consumers, one for each partition. Both reading and writing are performed in go routines.

In the log below, it goes 7 seconds without receiving a message and then receives bursts. I'm using Confluent's platform so I recognize that there will be some network latency but not to the degree that I'm seeing.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    kafka "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/sasl/plain"
)

func newDialer(clientID, username, password string) *kafka.Dialer {
    mechanism := plain.Mechanism{
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    rootCAs, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if rootCAs == nil {
        rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
    }

    return &kafka.Dialer{
        Timeout:       10 * time.Second,
        DualStack:     true,
        ClientID:      clientID,
        SASLMechanism: mechanism,
        TLS: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: false,
            RootCAs:            rootCAs,
        },
    }
}

func createTopic(url string, topic string, dialer *kafka.Dialer) {
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    controller, err := conn.Controller()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var controllerConn *kafka.Conn
    controllerConn, err = dialer.Dial("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(controller.Host, strconv.Itoa(controller.Port)))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer controllerConn.Close()

    topicConfigs := []kafka.TopicConfig{
        {
            Topic:             topic,
            NumPartitions:     6,
            ReplicationFactor: 3,
        },
    }

    err = controllerConn.CreateTopics(topicConfigs...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

}

func newWriter(url string, topic string, dialer *kafka.Dialer) *kafka.Writer {
    return kafka.NewWriter(kafka.WriterConfig{
        Brokers:      []string{url},
        Topic:        topic,
        Balancer:     &kafka.CRC32Balancer{},
        Dialer:       dialer,
        BatchSize:    10,
        BatchTimeout: 1 * time.Millisecond,
    })
}

func newReader(url string, topic string, partition int, dialer *kafka.Dialer) *kafka.Reader {

    return kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:   []string{url},
        Topic:     topic,
        Dialer:    dialer,
        Partition: partition,
    })
}

func read(url string, topic string, dialer *kafka.Dialer, partition int) {

    reader := newReader(url, topic, partition, dialer)
    defer reader.Close()
    for {
        msg, err := reader.ReadMessage(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        log.Printf("rec%d:\t%s\n", partition, msg.Value)
    }
}
func write(url string, topic string, dialer *kafka.Dialer) {
    writer := newWriter(url, topic, dialer)
    defer writer.Close()
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        v := []byte("V" + strconv.Itoa(i))
        log.Printf("send:\t%s\n", v)
        msg := kafka.Message{ Key: v, Value: v }
        err := writer.WriteMessages(context.Background(), msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func main() {
    url := "_______.______.___.confluent.cloud:9092"
    topic := "test"
    username := "________________"
    password := "________________"
    clientID := "________________"
    dialer := newDialer(clientID, username, password)
    ctx := context.Background()
    createTopic(url, topic, dialer)
    for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
        go read(url, topic, dialer, i)
    }

    go write(url, topic, dialer)
    <-ctx.Done()
}
```

Which is logging the below.

```
2020/11/02 23:19:22 send:       V0
2020/11/02 23:19:23 send:       V1
2020/11/02 23:19:23 send:       V2
2020/11/02 23:19:23 send:       V3
2020/11/02 23:19:24 send:       V4
2020/11/02 23:19:24 send:       V5
2020/11/02 23:19:24 send:       V6
2020/11/02 23:19:25 send:       V7
2020/11/02 23:19:25 send:       V8
2020/11/02 23:19:25 send:       V9
2020/11/02 23:19:25 send:       V10
2020/11/02 23:19:26 send:       V11
2020/11/02 23:19:26 send:       V12
2020/11/02 23:19:26 send:       V13
2020/11/02 23:19:26 send:       V14
2020/11/02 23:19:26 send:       V15
2020/11/02 23:19:27 send:       V16
2020/11/02 23:19:27 send:       V17
2020/11/02 23:19:27 send:       V18
2020/11/02 23:19:27 send:       V19
2020/11/02 23:19:28 send:       V20
2020/11/02 23:19:29 send:       V21
2020/11/02 23:19:29 send:       V22
2020/11/02 23:19:29 send:       V23
2020/11/02 23:19:29 send:       V24
2020/11/02 23:19:29 send:       V25
2020/11/02 23:19:30 send:       V26
2020/11/02 23:19:30 send:       V27
2020/11/02 23:19:30 send:       V28
2020/11/02 23:19:30 send:       V29
2020/11/02 23:19:31 send:       V30
2020/11/02 23:19:31 send:       V31
2020/11/02 23:19:31 send:       V32
2020/11/02 23:19:32 send:       V33
2020/11/02 23:19:32 send:       V34
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V8
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V14
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V15
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V16
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V17
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V20
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V21
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V23
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec3:       V29
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec1:       V0
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec1:       V9
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec1:       V22
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec1:       V28
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V4
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V5
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V7
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V10
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V11
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V12
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V18
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V24
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V25
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V30
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec4:       V31
2020/11/02 23:19:32 send:       V35
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec5:       V1
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec5:       V2
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec5:       V3
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec5:       V34
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec2:       V6
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec2:       V13
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec2:       V26
2020/11/02 23:19:32 rec2:       V33
2020/11/02 23:19:32 send:       V36
2020/11/02 23:19:33 send:       V37
2020/11/02 23:19:33 send:       V38
2020/11/02 23:19:33 send:       V39
2020/11/02 23:19:33 send:       V40
2020/11/02 23:19:33 send:       V41
2020/11/02 23:19:33 rec0:       V19
2020/11/02 23:19:33 rec0:       V27
2020/11/02 23:19:33 rec0:       V32
2020/11/02 23:19:34 send:       V42
2020/11/02 23:19:34 send:       V43
2020/11/02 23:19:34 send:       V44
2020/11/02 23:19:34 send:       V45
2020/11/02 23:19:34 send:       V46
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V47
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V48
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V49
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V50
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V51
2020/11/02 23:19:35 send:       V52
2020/11/02 23:19:36 send:       V53
2020/11/02 23:19:36 send:       V54
2020/11/02 23:19:36 send:       V55
2020/11/02 23:19:36 send:       V56
2020/11/02 23:19:36 send:       V57
2020/11/02 23:19:37 send:       V58
2020/11/02 23:19:37 send:       V59
2020/11/02 23:19:37 send:       V60
2020/11/02 23:19:38 send:       V61
2020/11/02 23:19:38 send:       V62
2020/11/02 23:19:38 send:       V63
2020/11/02 23:19:38 send:       V64
2020/11/02 23:19:38 send:       V65
2020/11/02 23:19:39 send:       V66
2020/11/02 23:19:39 send:       V67
2020/11/02 23:19:39 send:       V68
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V69
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V70
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V71
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V72
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V73
2020/11/02 23:19:40 send:       V74
2020/11/02 23:19:41 send:       V75
2020/11/02 23:19:41 send:       V76
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V41
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V56
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V68
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V74
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V75
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec1:       V76
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V37
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V40
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V42
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V48
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V55
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V57
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V60
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V61
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec3:       V62
2020/11/02 23:19:41 send:       V77
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V38
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V39
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V45
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V46
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V47
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V53
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V59
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V70
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V71
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec4:       V73
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V35
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V36
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V43
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V49
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V54
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V63
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V69
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec5:       V77
2020/11/02 23:19:41 send:       V78
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V44
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V50
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V51
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V64
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V65
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V66
2020/11/02 23:19:41 rec2:       V72
2020/11/02 23:19:41 send:       V79
2020/11/02 23:19:42 send:       V80
2020/11/02 23:19:42 send:       V81
2020/11/02 23:19:42 send:       V82
2020/11/02 23:19:42 send:       V83
2020/11/02 23:19:42 send:       V84
2020/11/02 23:19:43 send:       V85
2020/11/02 23:19:43 rec0:       V52
2020/11/02 23:19:43 rec0:       V58
2020/11/02 23:19:43 rec0:       V67
2020/11/02 23:19:43 send:       V86
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Edit:

The buffering is definitely just happening with Kafka-Go. Sarama does not encounter the same behavior:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"

    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"

    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var (
    broker   = "___-_____.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"
    brokers  = []string{broker}
    clientID = "___________"
    username = "___________"
    password = "___________"
    topic    = "sarama"
)

func main() {

    log.Printf("Kafka brokers: %s", strings.Join(brokers, ", "))
    ctx := context.Background()
    sync := newSyncProducer()
    // accessLog := newAsyncProducer()

    createTopic(topic)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; ; i++ {
            v := sarama.StringEncoder(fmt.Sprintf("V%d", i))

            p, o, err := sync.SendMessage(&sarama.ProducerMessage{
                Topic: topic,
                Value: v,
            })
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("sent\t\t%v\tp: %d\toffset: %d\t\n", v, p, o)
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    ps := []sarama.PartitionConsumer{}
    offset := int64(0)

    loop := func(msgs <-chan *sarama.ConsumerMessage) {
        for msg := range msgs {
            fmt.Printf("recv:\t\t%s\tp: %d\toffset: %d\n", msg.Value, msg.Partition, msg.Offset)
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
        ps = append(ps, createPartitionConsumer(topic, int32(i), offset))
    }

    for _, p := range ps {
        go loop(p.Messages())
    }
    <-ctx.Done()

}

func createPartitionConsumer(topic string, partition int32, offset int64) sarama.PartitionConsumer {
    config := baseConfig()
    c, err := sarama.NewConsumer(brokers, config)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    p, err := c.ConsumePartition(topic, partition, offset)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return p
}

func createTopic(topic string) {
    config := baseConfig()
    admin, err := sarama.NewClusterAdmin(brokers, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while creating cluster admin: ", err.Error())
    }
    defer func() { _ = admin.Close() }()
    err = admin.CreateTopic(topic, &sarama.TopicDetail{
        NumPartitions:     6,
        ReplicationFactor: 3,
    }, false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while creating topic: ", err.Error())
    }
}

func baseConfig() *sarama.Config {
    rootCAs, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if rootCAs == nil {
        rootCAs = x509.NewCertPool()
    }

    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Version = sarama.MaxVersion
    config.Net.TLS.Enable = true
    config.Net.TLS.Config = &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            rootCAs,
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
    }

    config.ClientID = clientID
    config.Net.SASL.Enable = true
    config.Net.SASL.Password = password
    config.Net.SASL.User = username
    return config
}

func newSyncProducer() sarama.SyncProducer {

    config := baseConfig()
    config.Producer.RequiredAcks = sarama.WaitForAll
    config.Producer.Retry.Max = 10
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true

    producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(brokers, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to start Sarama producer:", err)
    }

    return producer
}
```

In fact, in some cases it actually receives before the sent is confirmed which makes me wonder if there is internal messaging occurring and if so, if I should care...

```
recv:           V1176   p: 1    offset: 355
recv:           V1177   p: 2    offset: 363
send:           V1177   p: 2    offset: 363
send:           V1178   p: 5    offset: 377
recv:           V1178   p: 5    offset: 377
recv:           V1179   p: 1    offset: 356
send:           V1179   p: 1    offset: 356
send:           V1180   p: 1    offset: 357
recv:           V1180   p: 1    offset: 357
recv:           V1181   p: 1    offset: 358
send:           V1181   p: 1    offset: 358
send:           V1182   p: 4    offset: 393
recv:           V1182   p: 4    offset: 393
send:           V1183   p: 4    offset: 394
recv:           V1183   p: 4    offset: 394
send:           V1184   p: 3    offset: 358
recv:           V1184   p: 3    offset: 358
send:           V1185   p: 2    offset: 364
recv:           V1185   p: 2    offset: 364
send:           V1186   p: 3    offset: 359
recv:           V1186   p: 3    offset: 359
recv:           V1187   p: 3    offset: 360
send:           V1187   p: 3    offset: 360
send:           V1188   p: 5    offset: 378
recv:           V1188   p: 5    offset: 378
send:           V1189   p: 2    offset: 365
recv:           V1189   p: 2    offset: 365
recv:           V1190   p: 4    offset: 395
send:           V1190   p: 4    offset: 395
send:           V1191   p: 1    offset: 359
recv:           V1191   p: 1    offset: 359
send:           V1192   p: 4    offset: 396
recv:           V1192   p: 4    offset: 396
send:           V1193   p: 0    offset: 431
recv:           V1193   p: 0    offset: 431
send:           V1194   p: 4    offset: 397
recv:           V1194   p: 4    offset: 397
recv:           V1195   p: 2    offset: 366
send:           V1195   p: 2    offset: 366
send:           V1196   p: 3    offset: 361
recv:           V1196   p: 3    offset: 361
```

Comment: To check regards internal messaging you can write through sarama and read with go-karma and vice-versa. That would also help to understand if delays on write or read side.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok same issue occurs with Sarama write, Kafka-Go read unless I specify a MinBytes and MaxBytes on the reader. If I set it to `MinBytes:1` `MaxBytes:2` then it reads in sync but catching up to the highwatermark takes forever. If I set it to `MinBytes:1` `MaxBytes:1e10` then it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `ReaderConfig.MinBytes`, otherwise `segmentio/kafka-go` will set it to `1e6 = 1 MB`, and in that case, Kafka will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request.

```golang
func newReader(url string, topic string, partition int, dialer *kafka.Dialer) *kafka.Reader {

    return kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:   []string{url},
        Topic:     topic,
        Dialer:    dialer,
        Partition: partition,
        MinBytes:  1,         // same value of Shopify/sarama 
        MaxBytes:  57671680,
    })
}
```

On the other hand, the default for `shopify/sarama` is 1 byte.

References:

- [segmentio/kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/blob/7bc240457cc0879290c3bdbe4ea988d113e017d8/reader.go#L579-L585)
- [Shopify/sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/22788cceb16f663d67d3d60284bb8245c9437858/config.go#L306-L310)

Comment: You actually have to set both `MinBytes` and `MaxBytes` as it'll error out otherwise. I'm currently using `MinBytes:1, MaxBytes:2` unfortunately. When there are a lot of messages, it doesn't batch at all and becomes much slower than Sarama.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better way to accomplish this but kafka-go seems to use `MaxWait` to actually timeout their own connection. I'll edit your answer and mark it as the solution as it does solve the question presented.

Comment: `MaxBytes` should be much bigger than 2 in the common case. FYI, Java client default is 57671680.